# Why does transforming from Earth coordinates to galactocentric coordinates in astropy not preserve distances?

Tags: python, debugging, astropy

I'm converting `GCRS` objects to galactocentric coordinates and finding that distances between two points are not preserved under this transformation.

```python
import astropy.units
import astropy.coordinates
import astropy.time
from numpy.linalg import norm

t = astropy.time.Time('1999-01-01T00:00:00.123456789')

def earth2galaxy(lat):
    '''                                                                         
    Convert an Earth coordinate to a galactocentric coordinate.                 
    '''
    # get GCRS coordinates                                                      
    earth = astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation(lat=lat*astropy.units.deg,
                                            lon=0,
                                            height=0)
    pos, _ = earth.get_gcrs_posvel(obstime=t)
    cartrep = astropy.coordinates.CartesianRepresentation(pos.xyz,
                                                          unit=astropy.units.m)

    gcrs = astropy.coordinates.GCRS(cartrep)

    # convert GCRS to galactocentric                                            
    gc = gcrs.transform_to(astropy.coordinates.Galactocentric)

    return earth, gcrs, gc

earthA, gcrsA, gcA = earth2galaxy(0)
earthB, gcrsB, gcB = earth2galaxy(0.01)

print(norm(earthA-earthB))
print(norm(gcrsA.cartesian.xyz-gcrsB.cartesian.xyz))
print(norm(gcA.cartesian.xyz-gcB.cartesian.xyz))
```

This code gives

```
1105.74275693
1105.74275232
971.796949054
```

I find that this isn't a problem for larger distances (e.g. latitude offsets in the 10s of degrees).

I was previously getting around this by -- given points `A` and `B` -- transforming points `A` and `C = A + c*AB`, where `c` is some large number. I would then recover the transformed `B'` by undoing this scaling `B' = A' +  A'C' / c`. However, it feels like I should address the actual root of the problem instead of this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may simply be a floating point precision problem. If I look at the cartesian values, `x`, `y` and `z` are of order `1e6`, `1e6` and `1e2` for the GCRS frame, but they are of order `1e20`, `1e10` and `1e17`, respectively, for the Galactic frame.

Given a precision of `1e-15` for 8 byte floating point numbers (`numpy.finfo('f8').eps`), that means the `x`-value of the Galactic coordinate can only be precise to about `1e5` (meters). Then taking the norm (with the `x`-value uncertainty dominating), would lead to an accuracy of order `1e5` meters as well, much more than the actual separation.

The fact that the calculated values are still close to each other is largely luck (though it'll have an underlying reason, such as deviations averaging out somewhat).

This also agrees with the fact that you don't see a problem (or less of a problem) for larger offsets. Though testing it myself, I still see difference, of order `1e4`~`1e5`). To be precise, using 0 and 10 latitude, I obtain:

```
GCRS:     1104451.74511518
Galactic: 1108541.8206286128
```

If my assumption is correct, then my advice is simple: use the appropriate coordinate system for your coordinates, and take into account the relevant uncertainties (both machine precision and that of the coordinate system used).

Answer (score 1):

I think "0 0" mostly hit the nail on the head, but there's an alternate solution for this case: to use a float dtype that has more precision - e.g. the `float128` dtype (which you'd pass in to the `dtype` keyword of `CartesianRepresentation`), probably the distance *would* be much closer.

Unfortunately, there's a bug that seems to be forcing the dtypes back to `float64` (which I reported: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/8870), but if that's fixed, depending on your computer and what precision it supports, using a higher-precision dtype might do it.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but would [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) be the relevant (NumPy)  documentation on float128? Because that's also a bit disappointing perhaps: "In spite of the names, np.float96 and np.float128 provide only as much precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds."

Comment: Yes, that's true. If you have Solaris machine apparently that's true 128 bit but on x86_64 (which I suspect is what most people have), it's the 80, which is only 1e-15 -> 1e-18.  But for the OP's original case, that makes a big difference since they're right at the 1e-15 edge I think?